# How to make a browser open unsecured links without showing a error message

Tags: java, android, android-studio, browser, android-webview

I am developing a `web browser app` to open only one specific link and no other options to open other links. With this app when I put a default link: **https://www.google.com** or any other links, the app works fine and it opens the link. But the link I want my app to open it is not opening and it is not even showing any error message. The link is this **https://www.rdl.co.zw** If I open this link with most known browsers like chrome and browser they show a `security warning message` with an option to continue or go back to safety. If I press continue the site will open. So what is the problem with my code and which code am I suppose to add to make my simple browser open this link even if the link is not secure. I want to open the link without showing a security warning message.

> **Check my code below and help me with what to add to make my app 
>   function:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
SharedPreferences data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    swipe=(SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            webAction();
        }
    });


    webAction();


}

private void webAction() {
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.rdl.co.zw");
    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        finish();
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your manifest file and let me know if it solved your problem

```
<manifest>
  <application>
     <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
        android:value="false" />

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Nothing has changed